# Accessing Video frames from vidyo.io

Tags: vidyo

I am trying to access video frames.I have registered LocalCameraFrameListener but the function
 - (void)onLocalCameraFrame:(VCLocalCamera *)localCamera VideoFrame:(VCVideoFrame *)videoFrame is not getting called.

I am using the code given in the getting started "Access Raw Frames".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found how to get videoFrame:
1) Your viewController should be like:

```
class StreamController: UIViewController, VCConnectorIConnect, VCConnectorIRegisterLocalCameraEventListener,  VCConnectorIRegisterLocalCameraFrameListener {
    ...
}
```

2) Then you should register cameraframelistener in func onLocalCameraSelected:

```
func onLocalCameraSelected(_ localCamera: VCLocalCamera!) {
    self.connector?.registerLocalCameraFrameListener(self, localCamera: localCamera, width: UInt32(width), height: UInt32(height), frameInterval: 0)
}
```

3) So in onLocalCameraFrame func you will get videoFrame:

```
func onLocalCameraFrame(_ localCamera: VCLocalCamera!, videoFrame: VCVideoFrame!) {
   print(videoFrame)
}
```

But my problem is that I couldn't get Image from this videoFrame.
If you will find how to get UIImage or base64encoded image, please let me know.